# Change view button text in Woocommerce My account orders table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, orders

I would like to customize My account > Orders page, changing from action column, the "view" button text to "view tickets" in the Orders list table.

Is it possible to do it only on My account > Orders page?

Here is a screenshot for clarifications:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To rename **My account** > **Orders**: **"view"** action button text, use the following:

```
// Rename My account > Orders "view" action button text
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'change_my_account_my_orders_view_text_button', 10, 2 );
function change_my_account_my_orders_view_text_button( $actions, $order ) {
    $actions['view']['name'] = __( 'View ticket', 'woocommerce' );

    return $actions;
}
```

To Rename My account "Orders" menu item, use the following *(if needed)*:

```
// Rename My account "Orders" menu item
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'rename_my_account_orders_menu_item', 22, 1 );
function rename_my_account_orders_menu_item( $items ) {
    $items['orders'] = __("Ticket Orders", "woocommerce");

    return $items;
}
```

Code goes in *`function.php`* file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*. Tested and works.

[image]

---

If you need to target only My account > "orders" table, use `is_wc_endpoint_url('orders')` conditional tag:

```
// Rename My account > Orders "view" action button text
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'change_my_account_my_orders_view_text_button', 10, 2 );
function change_my_account_my_orders_view_text_button( $actions, $order ) {
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'orders' ) ) 
        $actions['view']['name'] = __( 'View ticket', 'woocommerce' );

    return $actions;
}
```

Code goes in *`function.php`* file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*. Tested and works.

Comment: That's True, it worked fine thank you so much it helped alot .. what if i want to add this order table to show again at the main page, the my-account dashboard after the text like this exactly.

https://yithemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/052.jpg

But change recent orders text to ticket orders .. can i ?