# Move an action button first in WooCommerce My account Orders page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

Is it possible to always keep a specific action button first in the WooCommerce My Account Orders page?

I have a plugin which creates a "track" button once the order is shipped, and I'd like that button to always be first in the list, as you see it appears second.

[image: screenshot]

and the HTML code of that Track button:

```
<a href="tools.usps.com/go/…" class="woocommerce-button button ast_track">Track</a>
```

I tried to use the following jQuery code with no luck:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation .track').prependTo('.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation');
});
```

Comment: Which plugin? Nobody can guess that by magic…

Comment: WooCommerce Shipment Tracking Pro from PluginHive. I was thinking a solution wouldn't be specific to it

Comment: As this plugin is commercial, you should add in your question the related generated html code portion and a/some screenshot(s)… Without that nobody will be able to help you… See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Screenshot posted, thanks! Will post htnl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following *(unstested)* based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55213027/3730754), to move "track" button first:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'my_account_orders_track_button_first', 100, 2 );
function my_account_orders_track_button_first( $actions, $order ) {
    // Targeting "track" params (button)
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'orders' ) && isset($actions['ast_track']) ) {
        // Save "track" params to a variable
        $action_track = $actions['ast_track']; 

        // Remove "track" params from $actions array
        unset($actions['ast_track']); 

        // Add back "track" params first in the $actions array
        $actions = array_merge(['ast_track' => $action_track], $actions); 
    }
    return $actions;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Comment: Thank you but this did not work. Here is the html of the actual track button, maybe this will help: <a href="https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction_input?qtc_tLabels1=9400%201000%200000%200000%200000%2000" class="woocommerce-button button ast_track">Track</a>